# Redis for Windows script debugger gets stuck

Tags: redis, redis-cli

Performing a simple test to debug a LUA script, `redis-cli` gets stuck and does not accept any input. They only way of ending the session is doing Ctrl+C

c:>cd "\Program Files\Redis"

```
c:\Program Files\Redis>echo return ARGV[1] + ARGV[2] > test.lua

c:\Program Files\Redis>redis-cli --ldb --eval test.lua , 2 3
Lua debugging session started, please use:
quit    -- End the session.
restart -- Restart the script in debug mode again.
help    -- Show Lua script debugging commands.
```

From that point the application does not accept any input.

I am using latest release (3.2.100) from https://github.com/MSOpenTech.

Do I need to do anything special to make the debugging work in Redis for Windows? 
I am not sure if the problem with debugging is because `redis-server.exe` or `redis-cli.exe`, since I do not have a Linux machine at hand.

**UPDATE**

I can now confirm I can debug a script using `redis-cli.exe` in windows, connecting to a Redis instance  in Linux. So the problem seems to be `redis-server.exe`.

Comment: It works on Linux, and my Redis version is 3.2.3

Comment: You used redis-cli in Windows to debug a script in a linux machine? or you did both things in Linux?

Comment: I did the whole test on Linux. Both my redis-cli and redis-server worked on Linux